# @Scheduled task does not start

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use the @Scheduled feature. I have followed [this](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html) and [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) tutorials but I can not get my scheduled task to be executed.

I have created a worker:

```
@Component("syncWorker")
public class SyncedEliWorker implements Worker {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void work() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        logger.debug("   " + threadName + " has began to do scheduled scrap with id=marketwatch2");
    }
}
```

and a SchedulingService:

```
@Service
public class SchedulingService {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("syncWorker")
    private Worker worker;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void doSchedule() {
        logger.debug("Start schedule");

        worker.work();
        logger.debug("End schedule");
    }
}
```

And tried different wiring in my applicationcontext. 
The final version looks like:

```
<beans xmlns=...
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation=" ..
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>
    <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="3"/>
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="3"/>

    ... Other beans...
</beans>
```

The server starts up with out any errors.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<context:annotation-config />` does not detect beans - it just processes the annotations on declared beans. Which means your `@Service` is not actually turned into a bean.

Use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcomany" />` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but the cause was different.
I had to add in my top project the following:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

When you add this, don't forget to also add to the correct place in your application context:

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
```

and:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
```